# Change id column name on Laravel 6.5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a model User in Laravel 6.5.1.

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public $table = 'usuario';
    public $primaryKey = 'cif_usu';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamp = false;

   //...
}
```

However, when I'm trying to select a user, I'm getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id" does not exist
>   LINE 1: select * from "usuario" where "id" = $1 limit 1 ^ (SQL: select
>   * from "usuario" where "id" = 24 limit 1)

How can I rename the id column?

Edit:

I changed:

```
public $primaryKey = 'cif_usu';
```

to:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'cif_usu';
```

and the result is the same

Comment: So, in your 'usuario' table the primary key is 'cif_usu'? Take a look at [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) on the docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a protected `$primaryKey` property to override this convention:

```php
/**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'key';
```

Read more about [Laravel - Primary Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the `$primaryKey` attribute should be `protected`. I think without traffic that change you aren't actually overriding the primary key in the base Model class.

If that's not the case it may be useful to see the code that triggers this query

Answer (score 0):

Put primarykey and table as protected.

```
protected $table = 'usuario';

protected $primaryKey = 'cif_usu';

public $incrementing = false; //only if your primary key is an assignable field,not auto incremented
```

You can use model as

```
DB::table('usuario')->where('cif_usu',$cif_usu)->first();
```

OR

```
DB::table('usuario')->find($cif_usu);
```